# Is associative binary operator closed on this subset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Here is the problem:

Suppose that $*$ is an associative binary operation on a set $S$. Let

$$H:= \{a \in  S\mid a * x = x * a \mbox{ for all }x\in S\}.$$

In other words, $H$ is consisting of all the elements of $S$ that commute with every element in $S$.

Show that $H$ is closed under $*$.

Comment: I thought that by the definition of a binary operation * on S, the set S was closed under *. Doesn't that mean the subset H is also closed?

Comment: No, it is "closed" on $H$ if for each $a,b\in H$, $a*b\in H.$ All you know from knowing $*$ is closed on $S$ is that $a*b\in S.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $a,b \in H$.  You must show that $a * b \in H$.  Thus, you must show that for any $x \in S$, $(a * b) * x = x * (a * b)$.

Here are some hints to get you started:

(1) Since $*$ is an associative operation, $(a * b) * x = a * (b * x)$.

(2) Since $b \in H$, $b * x = x * b$, so $a * (b * x) = a * (x * b)$.

Can you finish the proof from here?  You're going to use a series of steps that are each similar to either (1) or (2).

Comment: So, I would have to show that every combination of a, b, x satisfies the associative operation?

Comment: You know that the associative property holds for all elements of $S$.  What you need to show is that if you assume that $a$ and $b$ belong to $H$, then the element $a * b$ (which a priori is only known to be an element of $S$) is also in $H$.

Comment: So what else is left to prove if you showed that the associative operation holds for a and b?

Comment: You must prove "If $a, b \in H$, then $a * b \in H$."  This is NOT immediate and requires you to use both the associativity property of the operation (1) and the definition of the set $H$ (2).

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I got it. Using the start that @Michael Joyce gave me...

(1) Since ∗ is an associative operation, (a∗b)∗x=a∗(b∗x).

(2) Since b∈H, b∗x=x∗b, so a∗(b∗x)=a∗(x∗b).

---

(3) Since ∗ is an associative operation, a∗(x∗b)=(a*x)*b.

(4) Since a∈H, a∗x=x∗a, so (a*x)*b=(x*a)*b.

(5) Since ∗ is an associative operation, (x*a)*b=x*(a*b).

Since (a∗b)∗x=x*(a*b) then a*b ∈ H.

So, ***H*** is closed under *.

Comment: Ah, your right. I guess changed it.

Answer (score 0):

For $a,b\in T$, $a○x=x○a$, and $b○x=x○b$ $\forall x\in S$.

Now, $T$ is closed if $a○b\in T$.

Now, $(a○b)○x=a○(b○x)=a○(x○b)=(a○x)○b=(x○a)○b=x○(a○b)$ [Since, $T\subseteq S$, so $a,b,x\in S$ ○ is associative on S.]

Hence, $(a○b)○x=x○(a○b)$ $\forall x\in S$.
That is, $(a○b)\in T$.

So, T is closed under ○.